# Server Side render : 'css-loader/locals' generate different classNames then bundle.css - webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, isomorphic-style-loader

Trying to implement isomorphic rendering with my new project, so i read lots of articles fancy things like `css-loader`, state sharing etc,etc. So after some struggle somehow i render my page on server side with css locals.So i move on and start building other pages coz everything looks great, **until i didn't disable the javascript on my browser**.After that
I found the difference on html that i received from server have different css local className and the `bundle.css` has different. I really stuck.

Here is my `webpack.config`.I know i am doing something wrong.I appreciate if you point out.

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const context = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const config = {
    name:"client",
    context,
    entry: './App.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname+"/.build/assets",
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test:/\.(?:js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:css|less)$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                importLoader: true,
                                localIdentName:'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:7]'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'less-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                importLoader: true,
                                localIdentName:'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:7]'
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                }),
                exclude: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=1000&name=./fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash:base64:5]#icomoon',
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'bundle.css',
            allChunks: true,
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                // Mainly used to require CSS files with webpack, which can happen only on browser
                // Used as `if (process.env.BROWSER)...`
                BROWSER: JSON.stringify(true),

                // Useful to reduce the size of client-side libraries, e.g. react
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")

            }
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.json']
    }
};

const serverConfig = {
    name: 'server',
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    entry: [
        './index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './.build'),
        filename: 'server.build.js',
        publicPath: '.build/',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test:/\.(?:js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:css|less)$/,
                use: "css-loader/locals?localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:7]",
                exclude: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=1000&name=./fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash:base64:5]#icomoon',
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.json']
    }
};

module.exports = [config, serverConfig];
```

For Example : i got `.style__header__1H9xAC9` from server-side `html` and in bundle.css i got `.style__header__2uiLmVi` but if i enable JavaScript,
App render again in client side with same className that bundle.css contains.

Comment: i'm not sure but i don't think you should pass the `localIdentName:'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:7]'` both on the `less-loader` and `css-loader`

Comment: @Sag1v , thanks for suggestion , i tried that but didn't worked, same. 
After enable Javascript web-pack assign bundle.css classes to html.
but from server side the html classes are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling with this issue, i found my mistake is in `webpack.config`, i am using `context` in client side but not in server.
so i remove that from client and everything works great.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const context = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

const config = {
    name:"client",
    context,
    entry: './App.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname+"/.build/assets",
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
```

To

```
 const webpack = require('webpack');
 const path = require('path');

 const config = {
     name:"client",
//-----------xxx------------
     entry: './App.js',
     output: {
         path: __dirname+"/.build/assets",
         filename: 'bundle.js'
     },
```

Thanks, for your attention :)

Comment: wow...you are seriously my hero. would've never figured it out. worth a note in the docs for the css-loader